# Alguém já conseguiu utilizar o jQuery File Upload?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, upload

Me refiro ao deste link http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/.
A documentação é muito vaga. Já alterei o "action" do "form" mas sem sucesso.
Formulário html5:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="bloco_img_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
              <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="bloco_img_upload.php"></noscript>
              <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
              <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                  <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                      <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                          <span>Add arquivos</span>
                          <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                      </span>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                          <span>Iniciar envio</span>
                      </button>
                      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                          <span>Cancelar envio</span>
                      </button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                          <span>Excluir</span>
                      </button>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                      <!-- The global file processing state -->
                      <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- The global progress state -->
                  <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                      <!-- The global progress bar -->
                      <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                      <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
              <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
          </form>
```

bloco_img_upload.php

```
<?php
include("arq_pro.php");
include("../arq_fun.php");
include("redimagens.php");

$SqlMini=mysql_query("SELECT LarMinImg,AltMinImg FROM dados_config WHERE Emp=$EmpPess32 AND Bloco=$IdBloco32;");
list($LarMini,$AltMini)=mysql_fetch_row($SqlMini);

$targetFolder="imgclientes/".$EmpUrl1."/";
$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

$ContNot=0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["files"]); $i++) {
if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken){
    $tempFile = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $_FILES['files']["name"][$i], $ext);
        $ImgNome = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
        $ImgDir = "imgclientes/".$EmpUrl1."/".$ImgNome;
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$ImgDir);

        if(!is_dir("imgclientes/$EmpUrl1/")) {
            mkdir("imgclientes/$EmpUrl1", 0755);
        }

        if(!is_dir("imgclientes/$EmpUrl1/mini/")) {
            mkdir("imgclientes/$EmpUrl1/mini", 0755);
        }
        $ImgDirMini = "imgclientes/".$EmpUrl1."/mini/".$ImgNome;        

        $DimImg=getimagesize($ImgDir);
        $LarImg=$DimImg[0];
        $AltImg=$DimImg[1];

        if($LarImg<$AltImg){    
            $img = new canvas();
            $img->carrega("$ImgDir")
            ->redimensiona( 430, 620, 'crop' )
            ->grava("$ImgDir");

            $img = new canvas();
            $img->carrega("$ImgDir")
            ->redimensiona( $LarMini, $AltMini, 'crop' )
            ->grava("$ImgDirMini");
        }else{
            $img = new canvas();
            $img->carrega("$ImgDir")
            ->redimensiona( 640, 480, 'crop' )
            ->grava("$ImgDir");

            $img = new canvas();
            $img->carrega("$ImgDir")
            ->redimensiona( $LarMini, $AltMini, 'crop' )
            ->grava("$ImgDirMini");
        }

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `dados_img` SET `Emp`=$EmpPess32,`Bloco`=$IdBloco32,`Vinculo`=$IdVinc32,`Img`='$ImgNome';");

    } else {
        echo 'Tipo de arquivo inválido.';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Erro de validação.';
}
$ContNot=$ContNot+1;
}
?>
```

Esse é o erro mostrado após a tentativa de upload: Error Not Found.

O que eu devo alterar para funcionar no meu site em php?

Comment: é fácil a implementação para qualquer linguagem !!!

Comment: Mas quais campos de ser alterado? Onde colocar a pasta em que o arquivo de ser guardado(no caso do php)?

Comment: Fiz um exemplo logo abaixo como resposta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Baixe o pacote no [endereço](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tags)

**Solução Simples:**

## Html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo - JQuery Upload</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Css/jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<br>
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Escolha as Fotos</span>
    <input id="fileupload"  type="file" name="FilesPic" multiple data-url="salvar_foto.php">
</span>
<br>
<br>
<div id="progress" class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
</div>
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
<!---->
<div class="row" id="rowFotos"></div>
<!---->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Reset(){
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
    }
    $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                window.setTimeout('Reset()', 2000);                    
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Obs:* Html 5 e lembre-se de colocar na tag `<input id="fileupload"  type="file" name="FilesPic" multiple data-url="salvar_foto.php">`, o data-url sendo o seu script PHP ou a linguagem que está utilizando o arquivo correspondente.

## PHP

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['FilesPic'])){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FilesPic']['tmp_name'], 'Imagens/'. $_FILES['FilesPic']['name']);
        echo '1';
    }
```

*Obs:* o código simples em `PHP` já grava a solução de imagens, mas, claro você pode melhorar esse código para receber imagens de certo tamanho, receber somente imagens, etc. Também não esqueça de dar permissão na pasta Imagens de escrita.

## Diretório de Pasta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Obs:* Perceba que no item **Html** tem os `css` e o `js` devidamente conforme a disposição de pasta, então, tenha uma organização parecida como essa.

## Tela exibida no navegador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clicando no botão e escolhendo as imagens será enviado ao diretório Imagens (*Ref. Diretório de Pasta*)

Baixe o [Projeto](https://mega.co.nz/#!8pVQELoZ!_3xudFmgUz2A9n23g7ApS4gBZs_xaxhiUWzVnmEc3h8)

Comment: Obrigado. Salvou uma vida :)

Comment: user6026, Não entendi onde fica o limitador de tamanho da imagem no exemplo que você liberou para download!

Comment: a parte de deletar nao exibe