# Plugin para fazer upload de Multiplas imagens

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, upload

Tenho as seguintes classes no meu projeto.

`Galeria` e `Fotos`

Tenho uma `ViewModel` onde pego os dados da `Galeria` e dos dados das `Fotos`.

Ao fazer o submit (submit normal, não e assíncrono) Salvo a `Galeria` e as `Fotos` com a **ID** da `Galeria` criada.

Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, porém dependendo da quantidade de Imagens selecionadas a página fica parada e nenhum informativo do que está acontecendo aparece para o usuário.

Quero implementar algum Plugin para fazer isso, pesquisei muitos mas não consegui entender como aplico esse meu caso nos exemplos que vi.

Toda sugestão e bem vinda.

Comment: Tem esse (eu mesmo que deixei como resposta): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13606/alguem-ja-conseguiu-utilizar-o-jquery-file-upload/13613#13613, só a linguagem, mas, o plugin pode ser utilizado em diversas linguagens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um plugin muito utilizado é o [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). Baixe o pacote e disponha na sua aplicação `MVC Web`, como está nesse `html`. O `input` tipo `file` possui o nome de ***Filedata*** que será o mesmo nome resgatado na `Action` que vai receber tal foto, e possui um variável `idAlbum` que você pode se referir ao seu Album e na hora de gravar sua foto trabalhar com essa variável.

***Html***

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GravarFotos</title>
    <!--Ficaria assim a disposição-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--Fim da diposição-->
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <input type="file" name="Filedata" id="Filedata" />
    </div>
    <script>
        var idAlbum = '1';
        $(function () {
            $('#Filedata').uploadify({
                'swf': '/Content/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': '/Home/GravarFotos',
                'method': 'post',
                'formData': { 'idAlbum': idAlbum }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Código Action***

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GravarFotos()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public String GravarFotos(HttpPostedFileBase Filedata, int? idAlbum)
{
     Filedata.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/") + Filedata.FileName);
     return "1";
}
```

Existe mais itens nesse plugin que podem ser configurados, como demonstrado nesse [link](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/).

*Referências*

- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
- [Documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [PlUpload](http://www.plupload.com/), um plugin muito bom para fazer upload de vários arquivos!

Se o browser do usuário suportar HTML5 ele usa, caso não suporte, ele usa Flash, Silverlight, e por fim se não suportar nenhum destes, ele usa HTML4 para selecionar os multiplos arquivos.

Existe várias configurações disponiveis nele, inclusive você pode criar as suas. E exibe barra de progresso individual e global, e as miniaturas também!

Existe a possibilidade de configurar para ele quebrar o arquivo em partes, e ir enviando parte por parte, e no servidor ele junta tudo. Exemplo para enviar arquivos grandes!

Seu uso é bem simples e funciona em várias linguagens, inclusive fiz um post explicando passo a passo como utilizar ele com ASP .Net MVC segue o link:

[Usando Plupload com ASP .Net MVC](http://cleytonferrari.com/usando-plupload-com-asp-net-mvc/)

Precisando estamos ai pra ajudar!