# Multiplos arquivos para upload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Estou a procura de um plugin `Jquery` que faça Upload de vários arquivos ao mesmo tempo.

Alguém sabe de algum para me informar?

Comment: Marconi.. isso depende muito.. você irá precisar de múltiplas barras de progresso ?

Comment: Wisner Oliveira Preciso que ele deixe eu selecionar vários arquivos ao mesmo tempo, para upload. Não necessariamente preciso de barras de progresso.

Comment: Já tentou usar um HttpFileCollection ?

Comment: Nunca ouvir Falar, como seria feito?

Comment: Olha, uso o [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) e ele faz isso muito bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baixe o pacote [**jQuery-File-Upload**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tags), e faça uma pagina WebForm com esse contéudo:

***1 - WebFormUpload.Aspx***

Nessa página preste atenção nas referências que deve adicionar em sua página:

- `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`
- `<link href="~/Content/jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
- `<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
- `<script src="Scripts/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>`
- `<script src="Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>`
- `<script src="Scripts/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>`

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebFormUpload.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationForms.WebFormUpload" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Upload</title>        
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Escolha as Fotos</span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="FilesPic" multiple="multiple" data-url="MultiUpload.ashx" />
        </span>
        <div id="progress" class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="files" class="files"></div>
        <!---->
        <div class="row" id="rowFotos"></div>        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Reset() {
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
            }
            $(function () {
                $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    done: function (e, data) {
                        window.setTimeout('Reset()', 2000);
                    },
                    progressall: function (e, data) {
                        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                        $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Nessa linha `<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="FilesPic" multiple="multiple" data-url="MultiUpload.ashx" />` possui o endereço do arquivo MultiUpload.ashx que é o arquivo que vai receber os arquivos segue abaixo o exemplo do arquivo.

---

***2 - Handler.Ashx:*** *MultiUpload.ashx*

Após isso crie um arquivo `MultiUpload.ashx` e coloque esse modelo de código na sua aplicação:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplicationForms
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MultiUpload
    /// </summary>
    public class MultiUpload : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["FilesPic"];
            file.SaveAs(context.Request.MapPath("~/fotos/") + file.FileName);
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("1");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seguindo a referência dessa pergunta **Alguém já conseguiu utilizar o jQuery File Upload?** tendo essa [**resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13613/11549).